# Curly if statement inside curly braces in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, braces

```
<div class="temp_section" v-for="(item, i) in list" :key="i">
    <div>{{ item }}</div>
    <div class="curr_temp">{{ detail.data.temp_cur{{i}}}}</div> //<----Problem
    <div class="set_temp">{{ detail.data.temp_set{{i}} }}</div>
    <div class="minus">{{ detail.data.temp_sl{{i}}}}</div>
    <div class="chart" @click="chart{{i}} = !chart{{i}}">차트</div>
    <vs-dialog v-model="chart01">
        <chart01></chart01>
    </vs-dialog>
</div>
```

I want 'detail.data.temp_cur1, detail.data.temp_cur2, detail.data.temp_cur3....'
Is there any way to put i? Or should I use a different method altogether?
{{i}}............It feels like your brain is a potato.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
detail.data[`temp_cur${i}`]
```

Comment: it doesn't work but thanks.. The number became NAN...

Comment: it cannot become NaN if you have at least one element in the list. 
This will not work with @click, but  it should work for rendering content. Comment out the div containing click listener and try again.

Comment: Oh I see. Now I have to think about how to fix the click area..............Thanks!!